# Running SpecFlow Report - ERROR - The attribute "Label" in element <Target> is unrecognized

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, automation, specflow

I have been following the tutorial found [here](http://anoopjshetty.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/test-execution-report-in-specflow/) for a SpecFlow test report generator.

My issue is, when I run the tool, I receive the following message:

> The attribute "Label" in element Target is unrecognized

I've found a few possible solutions, none of which have worked e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363202/specflow-fails-when-trying-to-generate-test-execution-report)

I am able to show that I am running version 4.x as when I run MSBuild using the Visual Studio 2012, command prompt I can see the following:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929 [Microsoft .NET
>   Framework, version 4.0.30319.18052]

I have created a config file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363202/specflow-fails-when-trying-to-generate-test-execution-report)

but unfortunately I am still getting the error. The project is running locally off git and this issue has been fixed in the past by using the config file, however since swapping to a VMware Virtual machine, it is now occurring again.

I have also right clicked > Properties which states that the file is using .NET 4.0, in addition created a Environment Variable linking directly to the MSBuild directory. I've spent a good while browsing the internet and cannot get this working. Please help!

Many thanks for any help you can provide,

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved this with the internal devs. There was some problem with the Chromedriver update script which had been added by (I'm assuming NuGet)

Starting

```
<PropertyGroup Label="DownloadChromeDriverBuildTask">
```

and also:

```
<Target Name="DownloadChromeDriver" Label="DownloadChromeDriverBuildTask">
```

It was a small script that was installing ChromeDriver if it was not already available. Removing this seems to have resolved it. Hope this provides help to anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: In case somebody else is running into this, I had a similar problem except that it was the SlowCheetah extension in an Import tag that created the problem in my project file.  Instead of removing the extension, I just removed the Label attribute from the Import tag and that fixed the problem.

Comment: In which file did this appear?

Comment: In the project file (Rightclick on project > Unload project >Right click > edit file)